# Initialize class B with a const value from class A?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

How do I construct class B using a const value from class A, like so:

```
class A
{
public:
   A( );
private:
   B b_;
   const float PARAM_ = 7.7;
}

class B
{
    B(float param);
}

A::A() : b_( PARAM_ )
{

}
```

I am getting trash value in PARAM above when b_ is created instead of expected 7.7. What's the right way?

Comment: Put the definition for `b_` *after* that for `PARAM_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in C++ non-static members are initialized in order of declaration. `b_` is declared before `PARAM_`, so when you write `b_( PARAM_ )` in member initialization list, `b_` is initialized with garbage value and **then** `PARAM_` is initializated to 7.7. To avoid that, move declaration of `PARAM_` before `b_`.

Comment: That is true BUT you never (unless there is no other option) should write code which is dependent on order of declaration. It is very wrong programming practice. At least that is what they have taught me :) .

Comment: Works, but I really don't like that solution. :-(

Comment: @Danijel If value of `PARAM_` isn't intended to be set to different value by another constructor, it probably should be `static` as another answer says.

Answer (score 0):

If it suits your usage you could make the const static.
The problem occurs because the non-const version of your param wont have been initialised by the time you try to use it in b's constructor.

As a static it would be initialised earlier.